# pthread_sigmask interferes with GDB

Tags: c, gdb, pthreads, signals, sigint

I have been working on a multithreaded program under Linux with particular requirements about signal handling.
For instance, I need the program to print statistics for a single Ctrl-C input.

I implemented that using pthread_sigmask and sigwait, i.e. I block all the non-critical signals in the main thread before creating the rest of the threads and I start a "catcher" thread blocked on sigwait.

Initialization (in main):

```
sigfillset(&set);
sigdelset(&set, SIGSEGV);
sigdelset(&set, SIGBUS);
sigdelset(&set, SIGILL);

s = pthread_sigmask(SIG_BLOCK, &set, NULL);
if (s != 0)
    handle_error_en(s, "pthread_sigmask");

s = pthread_create(&signal_thread, NULL, &sig_thread, (void *) &set);
if (s != 0)
    handle_error_en(s, "pthread_create");
```

Catcher thread routine:

```
void *sig_thread(void *arg) {
    sigset_t *set = (sigset_t *) arg;
    int s, sig;

    pthread_detach(pthread_self());

    for(;;) {
        s = sigwait(set, &sig);
        if (s != 0)
            handle_error_en(s, "sigwait");
        switch(sig) {
            case SIGINT:
                break;
            case SIGTERM:
                break;
            case SIGUSR1:
                break;
            case SIGUSR2:
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
    pthread_exit(NULL);
    return NULL;
}
```

Everything works as expected, but my catching mechanism prevents GDB from pausing the program (the SIGINT routine is triggered).
How can I fix this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try pausing the program with `SIGSTOP` (instead of `SIGINT`) before attaching gdb.  `SIGSTOP` cannot be caught or ignored, and it will suspend your program until gdb is attached to it (and can then continue it).

Comment: Isn't there a way to override the standard GDB behavior ?

Comment: @ziu I don't know of any; a cursory look at the source indicates `inf_ptrace_stop` in `src/gdb/inf-ptrace.c` is hardcoded to use `SIGINT`.

Comment: Thanks for having a look into the code. Unfortunately, I cannot upvote you twice.